# Implementing check functions in C

Tags: c, function, methods, conventions

I've just written this code:

```
int is_write_mode(char * mode) {
    return !strcmp(mode, "wb");
}

int is_read_mode(char * mode) {
    return !strcmp(mode, "rb");
}

int is_valid_number(int number) {
    return number >= 0 && number <= MAX_LEN_STUDENTS;
}

int is_valid_grade(float grade) {
    return (grade >= MIN_GRADE && grade <= MAX_GRADE) || !grade;
}
```

And more functions like them to shorten the long if statements and to make the code more readable. I am now thinking if I should implement these functions like:

```
#define WRITE_MODE(x) (!strcmp(x, "wb"))
#define READ_MODE(x) (!strcmp(x, "rb"))
#define VALID_NUM(x) (x >= 0 && x <= MAX_LEN_STUDENTS)
#define VALID_GRADE(x) ((x >= MIN_GRADE && x <= MAX_GRADE) || !x)
```

Can you please give me and advice of how should I implement this kind of functions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `!grade` on a `float` does not look very healthy.

Comment: You really think that's more readable? And what about `while VALID_GRADE(array[i++]);` or `VALID_NUM(x >= 0 ? x : 0)`?

Comment: Using macros will not make the code more readable: quite the opposite IMO.

Comment: @WeatherVane My system works in a more different way. In short, it's something like an e-register and the user is entering students (which is a struct) and each student's grade (in the console). The tricky moment is that the input interrupts when the user enters a grade equal to 0. This is why I use ' || !grade'. (The grade range is 2-6)

Comment: Unless a function call proves to be a performance bottleneck, prefer functions to macros.

Comment: You still not explained why `grade` is of type `float`. Can it be say `3.75`? Your grade test will accept `0` as a valid grade, but doing a logical `!` (`NOT`) test isn't appropriate for a `float`.

Comment: I'm also at a bit of a loss to know why you want functions or macros to test file-opening mode, since the program author knows that already. And surely "write mode" can also be `"w"` and `"bw"` and `"wt"` and `"tw"`?

Comment: ... and if you want a function to test a "valid" number shouldn't you also pass the constraints as arguments? Why does this need a function at all? I think the question is nonsense.

Comment: Op's code is working (for the most part) and is seeking advice on improvements.  [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is a good place for reviewing working code.

Comment: I think that using functions is readable, specially when you debug, and it has the advantage that the compiler checks the types. If you're worried about the performance of calling small functions you can declare them as inline, although the compiler normally does this kind of optimization for you.